# Как определить точку пересечения между прямой и сплайном Catmull-Rom-а?

Tags: математика

Не используя численный метод желательно. Не охота перебирать числа.

Answer (score 0):

Сплайн Catmull-Rom описывается кубическим параметрическим уравнением от t. Прямую тоже описываете параметрическим уравнением от s. Приравниваете X-компоненты, выражаете s через t, подставляете в уравнение для Y-компонента, решаете кубическое уравнение, может получиться до трёх корней.

```
CX(t) = P0.x + (P1.x-P0.x)*s
s = (CX(t) - P0.x) /  (P1.x-P0.x)

CY(t) = P0.y + (P1.y-P0.y)*s
CY(t) - P0.y - (P1.y-P0.y)*(CX(t) - P0.x) / (P1.x-P0.x) = 0 // вот это решаете
```

Comment: А не надо еще проверить, чтоб точка пересечения попадала в сплайн? Решения-то могут оказаться точками за пределами сплайнового отрезка? Или я перавильно понимаю, что такое сплайн?

Comment: Да, верно, взять корни на отрезке 0..1

Comment: Ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Какое кубическое уравненение. У прямой нету момента времени t.

Comment: У, значит вам ещё немало предстоит узнать. Сплайн Кэтмулл-Рома описывается кубическим параметрическим уравнением. Прямую можно описать линейным параметрическим уравнением. Вообще напишите в вопросе исходные данные для своей задачи.